# How to use asterisk in cshell alias for ls command?

Tags: command-line, csh

Here is the explanation about my question:
normally we use command :

```
ls *test*
```

Output of this will be list of all files having "test" string in their name or 'No match'
Here I want an alias like:

```
lsa test         [This alias should expand in this : ls *test* ]
```

And when I don't give any argument the It should print all files like ls do

```
lsa              [This alias should expand in this : ls ]
```

I tried with this:

```
   alias lsa "ls '*\!:1**'  "
```

Also like this:

```
alias lsa 'ls "*\!:1**"  '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer so sharing here:
Above two alias were not working for me then I tried this and this is working.

```
alias lsa 'ls *\!:1**'
alias lsa "ls *\!:1**"
```

> Working in both the cases : **lsa** and **lsa test**

Still I need some explanation why earlier aliases were not working why this one works.